# How to dynamically include multiple pages in my JSP dynamically one after the other?

Tags: java, jsp, jakarta-ee

I am developing a testing tool for my project, where I have to include a JSP called Step inside my JSP based index page, whenever user clicks "add new step" link on my home page. I want all my included JSPs visible on my index.jsp. Is there any special command for such an arrangement?

Comment: You want links or the content  of all your JSPs on your index.jsp??

Comment: I want to allow users to add as many steps as they want. Now, my step.jsp page represents one step. So, If they click "add new step" button 10 times, then 10 step.jsp pages should be displayed one after the other on the same index.jsp page. I want such an arrangement